# NIntegrate methods with region

Tags: numerical-integration, regions

As of Mathematica version 10, one can integrate over regions (see https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/symbolic-geometry/integrate-over-regions.html )

As a toy example, I am using this from the documentation:

```
      \[ScriptCapitalR] = ConvexHullMesh[RandomReal[1, {50, 3}]]
      NIntegrate[x^2 y^2 z^2, {x, y, z} \[Element] \[ScriptCapitalR]]
```

I'd like to know what numerical method it is using for the integral, and what alternatives are possible.  When I select from the list of NIntegrate methods in the documentation (e.g., GlobalAdaptive, LocalAdaptive, etc) via

```
      NIntegrate[x^2 y^2 z^2, {x, y, z} \[Element] \[ScriptCapitalR], Method -> "GlobalAdaptive"]
```

it gives the error message:

Method "GlobalAdaptive" is not applicable for a region domain.  Continuing with method Automatic.

I can't figure out what method Automatic is calling (although it seems to be adaptive, based on some error messages I get when I try a highly oscillatory integrand).

Is there documentation somewhere of what methods can be called when NIntegrate is called over a region?

Comment: Mathematica accepts `Method -> "FiniteElement" `

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know if this is the default?  Or what other options work (other than going through them one at a time)?

Comment: I don't know, I tried it out.

Comment: Also, that method seems to not be listed here:
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html
Is there are more up-to-date list?  I was going to go through them, but the one you pointed out isn't even on the list so I'm wondering what other ones I'd miss...

Comment: `Method -> "InterpolationPointsSubdivision"`    works too

Comment: `Method -> "FiniteElement"` is not the default, which can be inferred from comparing outputs. (Difference of $\approx10^{-12}$.) Have you asked WRI your question? They might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, most of the methods of `NIntegrate` assume  the domain of integration to be a `Cuboid` in `n` dimensions and use it. In order to make integration over a `Cuboid`, the `Boole` command can be applied. For example,

```
SeedRandom[1234]; \[ScriptCapitalR] = ConvexHullMesh[RandomReal[1, {50, 3}]]
NIntegrate[x^2 y^2 z^2, {x, y, z} \[Element] \[ScriptCapitalR]]
```

> `0.0192459`

```
NIntegrate[x^2 y^2 z^2*Boole[{x, y, z} \[Element] \[ScriptCapitalR]], {x, 0, 1},{y, 0, 1},
{z, 0, 1}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]
```

> `0.0192453`

PS.That approach may be useful in the case of improper integrals. Compare

```
NIntegrate[ 1/Sqrt[RealAbs[x - y]], {x, y, z} \[Element] \[ScriptCapitalR]]
```

which returns the input with

```
NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[RealAbs[x - y]] Boole[{x, y, z} \[Element] \[ScriptCapitalR]], 
{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, Exclusions -> {x == y}, 
AccuracyGoal -> 4, PrecisionGoal -> 4,  Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]
```

> `1.65825`